# Textbox Autocomplete option in winforms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am facing an issue in textbox Autocomplete. I am binding the suggestion list with textbox dynamicly. When the list the bound successfully. I want autocomplete suggestions box should be opened automatically.

```
    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtStreet.TextLength <= 0 || txtStreet.TextLength % 3 != 0) return;

        _suggestions = GetSuggestions(txtStreet.Text);

        AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        collection.AddRange(_suggestions.Select(x => x.FullText).ToArray());

        txtStreet.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            txtStreet.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            txtStreet.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
            //SendKeys.Send("+^S");
        }));



    }
```

If I uncomment the sendkeys then it is working fine. But SendKeys is not good practice to use.
I just want to open the autocomplete suggestion box with code, without sendkeys or key press.

Comment: What's wrong with SendKeys() (when you have focused the *right* control)? It uses `SendInput()` (or, it should. To make sure, add `<add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>` in the `<appSettings />` section of your `app.config` file). Unless you want to use `PostMessage` (is it better?) or handle the `IAutoComplete` interface methods *manually*... Hoping that `OnTextChanged` is handling the `TextChanged` event of some other TextBox.

Comment: BTW, I don't know why you're trying to send this: `SendKeys.Send("+^S")`. You should probably send `txtStreet.Text`, e.g., `SendKeys.Send(txtStreet.Text)`

Comment: @Jimi I am sending a text which is not changing the user input value. Thats why I am adding "+^S".

Comment: Send keys is not recommended. there also a caution in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netcore-3.1                 If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided.

Comment: This is the only warning *If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided.*. hat you want to avoid is sending chars not handled by the Culture in use, generating Font Fallbacks in a Control when not expected. You're using it *internally*, I suppose, according the Current Culture, so no problems there. You can have a problem (a quite remarkable problem), if you move the focus while SendInput is processed. That you want to avoid at all costs. For the rest, it works well.